# Как парсить данные с одинаковыми классами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Как парсить данные с одинаковыми классами? На картинке у меня есть "Разработчик" с классом "dev_row" и "Издатель" с таким же классом, как мне спарсить только "Издателя". Ниже приведен код, который парсить данные со страницы стима, надо добавить еще и издателя.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 YaBrowser/20.11.3.183 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
}
FILE = 'games.csv'


def get_html(url, params=None):
    req = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return req


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='block_content page_content')
    games = []

    for item in items:
        date = item.find('div', class_='date')
        if date:
            date = date.get_text(strip=True)
        else:
            date = 'Date unknown'
        games.append(
            {
                'date': date,
                'developer': item.find('div', class_='dev_row').get_text(strip=True).replace('Разработчик:', ''),
                'description': item.find('div', class_='game_description_snippet').get_text(strip=True)
            }
        )
    return games


def save_file(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['DATE', 'DEVELOPER','PUBLISHER', 'DESCRIPTION'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['date'], item['developer'],item['publisher'], item['description']])


def parser():
    games = []
    with open("racesru.csv", newline='', encoding='cp1251') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            link = row[4]
            if (link != '0' and link != 'LINK'):
                url = link
                print(url)
                html = get_html(url)
                if html.status_code == 200:
                    games.extend(get_content(html.text))
                else:
                    print('Error')
    save_file(games, FILE)

parser()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: все же, "спарсить только Издателя" или добавить еще и "Издателя"?..

Comment: во фразе "только издателя" имелось ввиду, чтоб он был спаршен без разработчика (отдельно), а так, мне надо добавить издателя в список к date, developer и desription

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант, брать оба `div`-а с `dev_row` и отбирать из словаря Разработчика и Издателя:

```
rows = item.find_all('div', class_='dev_row')
games.append({
    'date': date,
    'developer': rows[0].get_text(strip=True).replace('Разработчик:', ''),
    'publisher': rows[1].get_text(strip=True).replace('Издатель:', ''),
    'description': item.find('div', class_='game_description_snippet').get_text(strip=True)
    })
```